# Error in Balloons demo from swift blog

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm completely new to Mac development and Swift language. I'm trying to run the Balloons demo from Swift Blog ([Here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=9)!) in the Playground but in the line:

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

I get the error:

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: SIGABRT
```

The console shows this:

```
2014-08-11 22:23:40.647 Balloons[484:303] +[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103d999d8
```

Since I'm new to Swift I have absolutely no idea whats going on. I've made no modifications in the original code.

Can anyone show me the light here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Xcode 6 (beta 5), and are you using iOS 7 or iOS 8 (I believe it's only available in iOS 8)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to meet requirements that are in the blog post :

> This playground uses new features of SpriteKit and requires the latest beta versions of Xcode 6 **and OS X Yosemite**.

The Balloons playground will not work on OS X Mavericks, even if you use the latest beta version of Xcode.

Comment: That is it! I'm running Mavericks. I missed the OS requirement since I'm running the "latest" version. Thanks!

Comment: Just installed Yosemite Beta 1. It all worked just fine. Thanks again.